# Does Android support Full Disk Encryption for mico SD Cards?

Tags: android, encryption, adb

Note: My Android is on Android 6.0.1 and is **NOT ROOTED**!

## **Androids default sd card encryption is file-based**

The default encryption for micro sd cards on Android appears to use file-based encryption. I put my micro sd card into my PC and all the file names were viewable. All file names, folders, etc. were viewable. It was just the content that wasn't viewable. This doesn't help in situations where the content of a file can be figured out by its name. Eg. MP3 files. You can also find out what apps are installed on the phone.

## **My Question**

I would like to know whether or not Android has an option to encrypt the entire sd card (file system). So instead of file contents being scrambled, everything is scrambled including the files and folders?

## **Known Solution**

The only solution I have found is to use **ADB Tools** to force your Android device to use your micro sd card as adoptable storage. This results in your micro sd card's file system being encrypted with 128 bit AES encryption. Take it out of your phone and put it in your PC and the file system is scrambled.

## **Why this solution isn't appropriate**

However this has the drawback of making your phone a lot slower (slower read-writes) and results in you no longer being able to view your phones internal storage. I copy files to and from my adopted-storage micro sd card via the adb tool commands: `adb pull` / `adb push`. If you try and copy your phones internal storage, you will only be able to copy the contents of your adoptable storage - as your adoptable storage becomes internal and access to internal becomes restricted/denied.

## **Updates**

I do not want to root my device.

#### **No Third Party Apps**

I do not want to create an encrypted file (via an app) within which to place files. That still wouldn't solve my problem and would likely cause more problems than adoptable storage; I'd suspect I would be using unstable and untested software. A solution would need to work on-the-fly (with no "go here, enter your password, mount, save file, unmount", etc.) with all software such as Music and Camera apps - with no problems whatsoever.

If you do have such a solution, feel free to add it but know that it doesn't properly solve the problem.

#### **Opinion**

Android advertises itself as supporting encryption. The fact that file names are viewable can be regarded as a security vulnerability.

Comment: For reference this link will probably provide an answer either way - https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk